# How to disable history?

Tags: configuration, mediawiki

Is it possible to configure MediaWiki to not keep a version history of each page?

When a page is edited, I want the old version to be gone forever.

How can I do this?

Comment: @leo instead of creating a history and deleting it, wouldn't it be better to just not generate it in the first place? Also, what is the right tool, then?

Comment: My point is that there is no simple way to prevent history to be stored, because MediaWiki was *designed* around the very idea of storing history. I have no ideas what your needs are, so it's hard for me to recommend a tool...

Comment: @leo If you think what I want to do is impossible, you're welcome to post that as an answer. Otherwise, I suppose not everyone can answer every question...

Answer (score 0):

If you are on MW>=1.21, you could hook into the [PageContentSaveComplete](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/PageContentSaveComplete) hook. This is after everything is written to the [database](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/MediaWiki_1.24.1_database_schema.svg) on saving an article. At this point, you'd query the database for all revisions for this [page id](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Page_table#page_id), and remove every revision except the newest. See [here](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/diffusion/MW/browse/master/maintenance/deleteOldRevisions.php) for an example of how you could delete a revision, and also [here](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/diffusion/MW/browse/master/maintenance/Maintenance.php) for how to purge the [text table](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Text_table) afterwards.

I have no idea if this appoach would be entirely waterproof.